# Can't add column in pgAdmin4 and PostgreSQL 9.5.25

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm working with pgAdmin4 and PostgreSQL 9.5.25 on Ubuntu 16.04 (I know it's outdated but I really need to work on it currently).

I can add a new table to my database, however, when I try to add a new column using GUI (Table --> Properties) to an existing table I get this error message:

```
ERROR   pgadmin:    Failed to execute query (execute_scalar) for the server #1 - DB:api_dev2 (Query-id: 1319646):
Error Message:ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NOT"
LINE 2:     ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS is_for_sale boolean DEFAULT Fal...
                          ^
```

The corresponding SQL query is  this

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."Products"
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS is_for_sale boolean DEFAULT False;
```

I know that "IF NOT EXISTS" is the source of the problem. When I simply run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."Products"
    ADD COLUMN is_for_sale boolean DEFAULT False;
```

it works. But why is this "IF NOT EXISTS" is added by pgAdmin4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS` is only available in [Postgres 9.6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-altertable.html) and up. See the documentation for [Postgres 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-altertable.html).

To address your edit, the version of PostgreSQL you are using is no longer supported - all supported versions support the `ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS` syntax which is probably why pgadmin assumes it is fine to use it. You could try to use an older version of pgadmin.